# center of a cluster of points and track shape

Tags: center, computational-geometry, point, centroid

I have plots of points which look like this.[image: x-y plot1] [image: x-y plot2]
[image]

The tracks which these points form can be a circle or an ellipse. Clearly the center of the circular tracks in the two images above are different.

**How can I find the center point of these tracks (circular/elliptical)?** I want to find the (x,y) coordinates which is the center, not necessary that it has to be a point that's in the plotted data set. i.e., I don't want a medoid.

EDIT: Also, **is there anyway that I can find an equation for circle/ellipse that envelopes a majority of these points?** In the elliptical track, I've added an ellipse that envelopes the points on the track. The values were calculated by trial and error. The center was also calculated by eye balling the plot. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: I take it just taking the average of x and y coordinates is not good enough for your purposes?

Comment: Yeah. Just taking the average doesn't always give me the exact center.

Comment: I guess you want some way to fit your set of points to an ellipse. Maybe you can just fit  z = p(x,y) where p is a quadratic polynomial and z is a variable you set to 0 to all data points using OLS? Then getting the center of ellipse should be trivial.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you elaborate on that a little more? I didn't get that.

Comment: Sorry, more of a half-baked thought. I was thinking you could try doing a fit of the form z = A1*x^2 +A2*y^2 + A3 x*y + A4 x + A5 y + A6, where z is "fake" variable you set to 0 for all data points. This gives you an equation for an ellipse, for which you can write the center coordinates as some function of the Ai coefficients. Not sure how well it will work in practice though.

Comment: "the exact center": are you kidding ?

Answer (score 2):

[Smallest circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) and the here is a paper (PDF download available) on the [smallest ellipse problem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.5019). Both have O(N) algorithms and should be able to provide the formula for the circle and area from which you can get the center. However, they focus on enclosing all of the points. To solve that issue you'll need to remove some a number of the bounding points, which you should get from the algorithms as well. Unfortunately, it's pretty much up to you as to what qualifies as a good enough solution.

A fast and simple randomized solution is:

1. Randomly divide the set of points into k sets of N/k points each.
2. Run the smallest circle/ellipse algorithm for each set
3. For each of the k sets, pick at least 1 but no more m bounding points to remove from main point set.
4. Return to step 1, t times.
5. Return the result of the circle/ellipse algorithm on remaining points.

The algorithm removes between k and mk bounding points every pass at a cost of O(N). For your purpose you'll probably want to remove some percentage of the bounding points, 1-25% seems like a good starting point. This solution assumes that k is very small compared to N, otherwise you'll be removing too many points.

A slower but likely better algorithm is useful in the case that you want to repeated remove one or all of the bounding point from the smallest elipse, recalculate the smallest ellipse, then remove the bounding points again.

You can do this by having the parent node be the bounding points (points stored as a set for easy for faster removal) of the smallest enclosing ellipse of it's children. The maximum number of bounding points should be no more than k (which I'm thinking is 9 for an ellipse, compared to 3 for a circle). So removing a point from the data structure at O(k log N) as it requires recalculating the smallest circle, which is O(k) for each parent that is affected which is O(log N). So removing m points from the data structure should be O(mk log N). You might also want to consider calculating the area of the ellipse every every removed point and removing every point for a cost of O(Nk log N) until you only have three points left. You could then analyze the area data to determine what ellipse should be used. A simple result would be to simply use the ellipse that has the area closest to the average area of all of the ellipses created, but may not be exactly what you seek. It also might be too slow, in which case I recommend a single pass of the faster algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an instance of Robust Ellipse Fitting. Check this paper: Outlier Elimination for
Robust Ellipse and Ellipsoid Fitting http://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.4610.pdf.

A first rough and easy solution is provided by the ellipse of inertia (2D version of the ellipsoid of inertia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_ellipsoid). Its center is just the centroid and axes are given by Eigen vectors/values of the 2x2 matrix of inertia.